# Display attributes of many to many relationship coded with @OneToMany and @ManyToOne

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-mvc, many-to-many, jstl

I'm a newbie in Spring. I think it's better to explain my problem with a little example. Let's say I have two main classes: `User` and `Group`. A `User` can be part of more `Group`s and a `Group`, obviously, can have more `User`s. So the relationship between them is many-to-many.  What I would like to show, is something like this (using JSTL):

```
<c:forEach items="${groups}" var="group">
    <c:out value="${group.name}"/> (<c:out value="${fn:length(group.users)}" />):<br />
    <c:forEach items="${groups.users}" var="user">
        <c:out value="${user.name}"/><br />
    </c:forEach><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Basically, the output should be something like:

> Random (2):
>   Joe
>   Bloggs
>   Star wars (5):
>   Luke
>   Chewbacca
>   Darth Vader
>   Princess Leia
>   Yoda
>   Nintendo (3):
>   Super Mario
>   Metroid
>   Zelda

I initially coded it with the classic `@ManyToMany` annotation, using an additional table `user_has_group` (created and managed by JPA) and it was working perfectly.

I needed to modify the structure since I needed the `user_has_group` table to have the `joined_date` column. To achieve it, I read online that the best solution is to create another class (i.e. `UserHasGroup`) and add the one-to-many relationships to this class from `User` and `group`. Doing so, it's possible to add additional attributes to the `UserHasGroup` class (and therefore additional columns to the `user_has_group` table). Something like:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String alias;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserHasGroup> userHasGroup = new ArrayList<UserHasGroup>();

    // Constructors/getters/setters
}
```

Group:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<UserHasGroup> userHasGroup = new ArrayList<UserHasGroup>();

    // Constructors/getters/setters
}
```

UserHasGroup:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_has_group")
public class UserHasGroup
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date joinedDate;

    // Constructors/getters/setters
}
```

So far, so good. All the tests run successfully and the functionality is maintained.

But I'm facing a problem with JSTL. In fact, with this new structure is obviously not possible to do `group.users` to iterate through the users.

What is the best way to reach the same functionality as before but with this new structure?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any problem with the additional info I have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why ${fn:length(group.userHasGroup)} should'n work.

The only problem you might come accross is some no active session exception. You can solve it either by

- using "open session in view" interceptor (which somebody calls an anti-pattern)
- manualy iterating through the list in your service method
- eager fetching the relationship - i would be very carefull here as this can lead to many queries to database

Answer to additional question:

It should look somehow like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${groups}" var="group">
    <c:out value="${group.name}"/> (<c:out value="${fn:length(group.userHasGroup)}" />):<br />
    <c:forEach items="${groups.userHasGroup}" var="userHasGroup">
         <c:out value="${userHasGroup.user.name}"/><br />
  </c:forEach><br />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @frant.hartm. You're right, this is a solution that would work. But now let's say that I want to show the users in the group... (edited the question accordingly)

Comment: Thanks! Yeh, sometimes I think I'm retarded.... (I'll award the bounty in 7 hours, now I can't)